# Scraping a table with BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a table with info on footballplayers on https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-city/kader/verein/281/saison_id/2019/plus/1

It works fine when I try to get information manually like this:

```
url = 'https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-city/startseite/verein/281/saison_id/2019'

response = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Custom5'})
data = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html.parser')

players_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "items"})

Players = soup.find_all("a", {"class": "spielprofil_tooltip"})
Players[5].text

Values = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "rechts hauptlink"})
Values[9].text

Birthdays = soup.find_all("td", {"class": "zentriert"})
Birthdays[1].text
```

But to actually get the data into a table I think I need to use a for loop with td and tr tags. I have looked for solutions but cannot find anything that works with this particular website.

When I try this for example, the list remains empty

```
data = []
for tr in players_table.find_all("tr"):
    # remove any newlines and extra spaces from left and right
    data.append

print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually append anything to the list.

Change `data.append` to `data.append(tr)`.

That way you tell the your program what to append to the list, assuming `players_table.find_all("tr")` does return at least 1 item.

Answer (score 0):

The website uses JavaScript, but `requests` doesn't support it. so we can use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) as an alternative to scrape the page.

Install it with: `pip install selenium`.

Download the correct ChromeDriver from [here](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads).

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from time import sleep

URL = "https://www.transfermarkt.co.uk/manchester-city/kader/verein/281/saison_id/2019/plus/1"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\path\to\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(URL)
# Wait 5 seconds for the page to load
sleep(5)

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, "html.parser")

players_table = soup.find("table", attrs={"class": "items"})

for tr in players_table.find_all('tr'):
    tds = ' '.join(td.get_text(strip=True) for td in tr.select('td'))
    print(tds)

driver.quit()
```